# Table view cell didn't show the full content

Tags: xcode

I created a tableview to shows some contents with subtitle.

and I chose the UITableViewCellStyleDefault.

so.in my mind, the table view should like this.

At the space will delete, I used _ the represent space

shopA_***_*__*_*__*_*__**_Floor 2

shopB_***_*__*_*__*_*__**_Floor 3

shopWithLongName_***_*_**_Floor 5

however, the output is like this

shopA____Floor 2

shopB____Floor 3

shopW...__Floor 5

but in fact there are lots of space after the subtitle : Floor

how can I put the shop name to left and subtitle to right? so that shopWithLongName can show it's full name.

Thank you professionals

---

it seems so complicated. Are there any easier options?

after changing to UITableViewCellStyleValue1. It becomes better

shopW.....***_*__*_*__*_*_**_Floor5

there are lots of space to show the full text.

why do it show .... instead of the full text??

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
return [Array count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by subtitle you mean secondary text you can't use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` this cell style *only* has one text string and one optional image, if you want secondary text you need to look at the documentation for UITableViewCell under the cell styles section and pick the style that you are looking for (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle). You might also want to take a look at some of the iOS5 table view stuff, there *might* be something that would allow you to take more control of the way the cells look.

Answer (score 0):

While preparing the cell better to add two labels.And make frames as your requirement.After that fill those labels with text.

Comment: Sorry, i would like to ask , how can I customize the cell according to your idea??

Comment: you cannot add labels to tableview directly.If you add your labels to cell they will be reflected in the uitableview.